# How to set proper JSON response for POST method in RESTful API from FOSRestBundle?

Tags: php, json, symfony, fosrestbundle, symfony-2.6

I am making a `POST` method for a RESTful API. The API is built on top of FOSRestBundle and NelmioApiDoc as you may notice. I am not able to validate when file is not uploaded or when `rid` parameter is missing and response with proper JSON. This is what I am doing:

```
/**
 * Set and upload avatar for reps.
 *
 * @param ParamFetcher $paramFetcher
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 *      resource = true,
 *      https = true,
 *      description = "Set and upload avatar for reps.",
 *      statusCodes = {
 *          200 = "Returned when successful",
 *          400 = "Returned when errors"
 *      }
 * )
 *
 * @RequestParam(name="rid", nullable=false, requirements="\d+", description="The ID of the representative")
 * @RequestParam(name="avatar", nullable=false, description="The avatar file")
 *
 * @return View
 */
public function postRepsAvatarAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher, Request $request)
{
    $view = View::create();
    $uploadedFile = $request->files;

    // this is not working I never get that error if I not upload any file
    if (empty($uploadedFile)) {
        $view->setData(array('error' => 'invalid or missing parameter'))->setStatusCode(400);
        return $view;
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entReps = $em->getRepository('PDOneBundle:Representative')->find($paramFetcher->get('rid'));

    if (!$entReps) {
        $view->setData(array('error' => 'object not found'))->setStatusCode(400);
        return $view;
    }

    .... some code

    $repsData = [];

    $view->setData($repsData)->setStatusCode(200);

    return $view;
}
```

If I not upload a file I got this response:

```
Error: Call to a member function move() on a non-object
500 Internal Server Error - FatalErrorException
```

But as Symfony exception error not as a JSON as I want and need, so code is never entering in the `if`.

If I not set `rid` then I got this error:

```
Request parameter "rid" is empty
400 Bad Request - BadRequestHttpException
```

But again as Symfony exception error and not as a JSON. How do I response a proper JSON if `rid` is not present or if file wasn't uploaded? Any advice?

Comment: you're missing `$uploadedFile` param or to set the variable.

Comment: @LordZed I have edited my answer, I have defined `$uploadedFile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$request->files` is an instance of `FileBag`. Use `$request->files->get('keyoffileinrequest')` to get the file.

`rid` is specified is a required parameter, so yeah, it throws a BadRequestHttpException if you don't set it. It behaves like it should. You should try setting `rid` to an ID that isn't in the database, then you should see your own error message.

If you want `rid` to be optional you could add a default value for `rid`:

```
* @RequestParam(name="rid", nullable=false, requirements="\d+", default=0, description="The ID of the representative")
```

Something like that. Now `rid` will be zero, your Repository::find call will probably return null and your error view will be returned. But I recommend that you keep it like it is, it is proper behavior.